# git merge changes from a local(?) branch to another local branch

Tags: git, gerrit

I have two branches that I care about brandon-gce and brandon/GCE_startsript. brandon-gce is an older branch from a few weeks ago and has some files on it that I need but were never merged upstream.

I want to pull all of the terraform changes on brandon-gce into my new brandon/GCE_startsript branch. I'm sure thats very straight forward and there are hundreds of explanations on how to do this, but I'm unfamiliar with git and am scared of making a mess that I don't know how to fix.

```
➜  terraform git:(brandon-gce) git diff --name-status brandon-gce..brandon/GCE_startsript | grep terraform
M    /terraform/environments/food/gcp-us-east4/pods.tf
M    /terraform/environments/food/gcp-us-east4/variables.tf
M    /terraform/environments/staging/gcp-us-east4/pods.tf
M    /terraform/environments/staging/gcp-us-east4/variables.tf
M    /terraform/modules/gcp-region/firewall.tf
D    /terraform/modules/screencast-gcp-pod/.gateway.tf.swp
D    /terraform/modules/screencast-gcp-pod/blargh.tf
M    /terraform/modules/screencast-gcp-pod/variables.tf
```

I was thinking I should do something like this. Is that right?

```
➜  terraform git:(brandon-gce) git rev-parse HEAD
7561c4083a742a6949cba397af964bff2a92765e
➜  terraform git:(brandon/GCE_startsript) git cherry-pick 7561c4083a742a6949cba397af964bff2a92765e
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from the new branch

```
git merge brandon-gce
```

Comment: Alright, so I've done that, but now I can't push my branch up to the origin. I use Gerrit.

git push origin HEAD:refs/for/develop
Counting objects: 27, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (23/23), done.
Writing objects: 100% (27/27), 5.44 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 27 (delta 19), reused 7 (delta 4)
 ! [remote rejected] HEAD -> refs/for/develop (change https://gerrit/8314 closed)
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://gerrit:29418/brando.git'

Comment: Have I messed up the ancestors of the branch? I'm not sure why this is now not able to go up. It has the same change-id associated to it

Comment: By this point you're asking a far different question than the one you asked.  I think I've adequately answered the question you did ask here, and a comment is not the place to revise your question or ask a new one.